Prolog predicate using lists
I have to make this programming exercise in Prolog.
Consider the following predicates:
race(name).
victory(pilot_name, race_name, date).
pilot(name).
Define the following Prolog predicate:
most_consistent(pilot_name): Returns true if the pilot has won the highest number of races.
I am not able to think about a simple solution to solve this. Anyone can help me?
I tried to use recursion but i can't come up with a solution

Using built-in predicates:
victory(p1, r1, _).
victory(p2, r2, _).
victory(p3, r3, _).
victory(p2, r4, _).
victory(p3, r5, _).

won_most_races(P) :-
    % Make list of wins
    findall(PI, victory(PI, _, _), PIs),
    % Sort the wins
    msort(PIs, SPs),
    % Make Person-Wins pairs
    clumped(SPs, PWs),
    % Switch to Wins-Person pairs (also sorts on Wins)
    transpose_pairs(PWs, WPs),
    % Reverse, for maximum Wins first
    reverse(WPs, RWPs),
    % Get the highest number of Wins
    RWPs = [H-_|_],
    % Identify the Pilot(s) with the max Wins (could be multiple)
    member(H-P, RWPs).

Result in swi-prolog:
?- won_most_races(P).
P = p3 ;
P = p2 ;
false.

